# setValue wont work though there is a value to use

Tags: java

Hi im trying to get a progress bar to work,I have a value and cann access the property here is my code just the form because i know progress being past because i can print it out useing getValue, here is my code

```
 /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package mashisgood;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JProgressBar;


    /**
     *
     * @author brett
     */
    public class MashForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
        /**
         * Creates new form MashForm
         */
        public MashForm() {
            initComponents();

        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            fileChooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jButton1.setText("jButton1");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jTextField1.setText("Add afile to compile");

            jProgressBar1.setToolTipText("");
            jProgressBar1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
            jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);

            jButton2.setText("jButton2");
            jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 289, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            jProgressBar1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("mystatusbar");

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                jTextField1.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
            }
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           //MashIsGood goodo = new MashIsGood();
           String[] arguments = new String[] {"1234"};
            try {

                MashIsGood.main(arguments);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MashForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }                                        
     void setPGValue(int progress) {

            jProgressBar1.setValue(progress);    
             System.out.println("Get Value:"+" "+jProgressBar1.getValue());
            jProgressBar1.setValue(69);

          setbar(progress);

        }
        public void setbar(int goods){
            jProgressBar1.setValue(goods);
            //System.out.println();
            //return 
        }
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MashForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MashForm().setVisible(true);

        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    public static javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   




}
```

Here is the second class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mashisgood;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author brett
 */
public class MashIsGood extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\Telegraph_Road.mp4", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\out.mp4");
          final Process p = pb.start();
        // create a new thread to get progress from ffmpeg command , override  
        // it's run method, and start it!  
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream());
                // Find duration  
                Pattern durPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Duration: )[^,]*");
                String dur = sc.findWithinHorizon(durPattern, 0);
                if (dur == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse duration.");
                }
                String[] hms = dur.split(":");
                double totalSecs = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(hms[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(hms[2]);
                System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalSecs + " seconds.");
                // Find time as long as possible.  
                Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=time=)[\\d:.]*");
                String match;
                String[] matchSplit;
                while (null != (match = sc.findWithinHorizon(timePattern, 0))) {
                    matchSplit = match.split(":");
                    double progress = (Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[0]) * 3600 +  Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(matchSplit[2])) / totalSecs;
                   // System.out.printf("Progress: %.2f%%%n", progress * 100);
                    MashForm pgbar = new MashForm();
                    int prog = (int)(progress * 100);
                    pgbar.setPGValue(prog);
                    pgbar.setbar(prog);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Your title claims that `setValue()` isn't working, but it must be if the results of `getValue()` are correct. What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I will not animate the progress bar im so lost... all night i have tried. But it still wont work

Comment: even just doing  jProgressBar1.setValue(25);  wont work for me

Comment: I cannot see where setPGValue or setbar is called and theese methods are the only places where you call ProgressBar.setValue.

Comment: It is called from a seperate class wich i will put up now

Comment: Beware of using `ffmpeg` in a process. It sometimes hangs if it uses to much cpu and/or ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class MashIsGood you create one MashForm object in every iteration of the while loop.
So you always set the values of a new progress bar of a not running instance and throw it away immediately.
You have to pass the running instance of MashForm to the Thread and use this instance.

Change and rename your main method of class MashIsGood to pass a MashForm instance (The renaming is only for not to confuse with the main entry method for start an application).

```
class MashIsGood  {
   //public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   public static void startThread(MashForm mashForm) throws IOException {
```

Then use this parameter to set the progress bar value;

```
while (null != (match = sc.findWithinHorizon(timePattern, 0))) {
    matchSplit = match.split(":");
    double progress = (Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(matchSplit[2])) / totalSecs;
 // System.out.printf("Progress: %.2f%%%n", progress * 100);
    int prog = (int)(progress * 100);

    mashForm.setPGValue(prog);// <-- Use mashForm
    mashForm.setbar(prog);
}
```

Then change your ActionListener in MashForm and pass the MashForm instance to startThread

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        // MashIsGood.main(arguments);
        MashIsGood.startThread(this);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MashForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
    }
}
```

And that is it. It works, I have tested it.

Comment: I dont seem to have getOneAndOnlyInstance it wont work, do i have to load somthing?

Comment: This method is only a 'placeholder' for something you should create. I will post an example in a few minutes.

Comment: Wow thank you so much Joachin. But i still cant get it working. but thank you so much i learnt alot from that help
Im not getting an error but the progress bar still isnt moving...

Answer (score 0):

Hi i took a look at it :)
I don't exaclty know what you are trying to do but

Change this

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {                                         
       //MashIsGood goodo = new MashIsGood();
       String[] arguments = new String[] {"1234"};
        this.main(arguments);

    }
```

to whatever you want the button2 to do :) for example

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {                                         
       //MashIsGood goodo = new MashIsGood();
       String[] arguments = new String[] {"1234"};
        setPGValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1);

    }
```

this will raise the value of your progressbar with 1 everytime you click on button 2 :)

Comment: Lol i'm just imagining how much you had to be smiling while answering this question... heh

Comment: Haha Im kind of new to programming myself so I was just happy I could answer a question for once. Didn't see that he posted another class though.

Comment: Thats awsome bbut how do i click button2 and have it complete?? insteat of having to click 100 times lol

Comment: Just change (JProgressbar1.getValue() + 1);
to (100);

Comment: Umbe not quite...lol id like to actually be accurate. Id like to click the button and it setValue based on the progress variable

Comment: In your meshIsGood class. Move the MashForm pgbar = new MashForm();
to outside the while loop